# Read gRPC repeated fields in Python

Tags: python, parsing, protocol-buffers, grpc, repeat

Maybe I did miss some key point in the documentation, but I am struggling to find some *easy*, *pythonic* way to read **repeated** gRPC fields.

Let's suppose we have some protodef:

```
message Bar
{
    repeated float vals = 1;
}
message Foo
{
    repeated Bar bars = 1;
}

service FooService
{
  rpc GetFoo(Foo) returns (Foo) {}
}
```

What would be an easy, pythonic way to read `Foo` and `Foo`'s `Bar` values in `GetFoo` (servicer side)?

Goal is to read the encapsulated repeated floats into separated lists or NumPy arrays.

I tried to access by index or loop through iterator-style, like:

```
...
def GetFoo(self, request, context):
    bar1 = request.bars[0]
    ...
```

Unfortunately, this raises exceptions that the message object `...has no len()` and simply iterating over the points:

```
...
def GetFoo(self, request, context):
    point_lists = list()
    for bar in request.bars:
         points = [v for v in bar]
         point_lists.append(points)
    ...
```

...raises an exception `Bar object is not iterable` so that I cannot loop through the single points (though I do not get atm why it says that `Bar` is not iterable when `Foo` is also a repeated type and *is* iterable).

Comment: You have no point in the code you show code where `len` is used (not even implicitly), so the error about missing `len` must come from somewhere else. Also, `points = [v for v in bar.vals]`

Comment: The `len` issue comes from the line `bar1 = request.bars[0]`. I will edit it to make this more clear.

Comment: @GPhilo edited. Just to be clear about the question: I do not care if I access by index, with an iterator, ... I'd just like to have an easy, pythonic solution to read/parse repeated fields into lists or NumPy arrays.

Comment: Ok, have you tried the second part of my comment above? Your definition for `points` iterates on the wrong item (you want to iterate on the `vals` of `bar`, not on `bar` itself)

Comment: @GPhilo I should get more sleep...such an unnecessary slip. Thank you very much for pointing out that, of course, it should be `bar.vals`.

Comment: We've all been there ;)